# snowflake sdk error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set') at OcspResponseCache.set

Tags: node.js, typescript, kubernetes, npm, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using node version v17.9.0.
OS is Linux.
I am using Kubernetes and launching a nodejs application to connect with snowflake and execute a query.

version of snowflake-promise is 2.2.0.
version of snowflake-sdk is 1.6.14.

I am getting below error while connecting to snowflake. Can you please suggest.

```
/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/ocsp_response_cache.js:157
    cache.set(certId, response);
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
    at OcspResponseCache.set (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/ocsp_response_cache.js:157:11)
    at /app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/socket_util.js:232:32
    at done (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/check.js:142:5)
    at ocspResponseVerify (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/check.js:201:7)
    at done (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/check.js:71:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/agent/check.js:99:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too..

This error occurs when you are working in organisation  environment!
You can reach Admin team to enable access to snowflake inside your deployment environment!! and if it is happening in local environment you need to enable proxies